# How to install alfresco on linux using puppet?

Tags: puppet, alfresco

I want to install the Alfresco Linux binary file on Linux using Puppet but I am not sure how can I provide arguments while installing such as below:

1. Do you want to install java?[y/n]
2. Do you want to install postgres?[y/n]
3. Do you want to install share?[y/n]
4. OpenOffice port[8081]:
5. Tomcat port[8080]:
   ..& so on.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why not use puppet to install Tomcat, the JRE, OpenOffice etc individually, then have puppet push out the wars and config for alfresco? Should be much simpler than trying to do the whole lot in one go!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on that https://github.com/jurgenlust/puppet-alfresco or maybe look on puppet forge